# Hide User-Control in Design Mode

Tags: asp.net, design-time

Controls in my ASP.Net (3.5) pages to simulate popups (Visual-Studio 2008).
The problem is that all these popups are positioned over the normal controls in the page in design mode. 
So my Question is: How can I hide User-Controls in Design-Mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From googling around a bit I don't think you can with an ascx. I think you should turn it into a custom control if you need this.

http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/189.aspx might help

edit: <strike>http://ajdotnet.wordpress.com/2006/08/28/do-you-value-design-time-support/</strike>

you might be able to do this if you create a custom control that holds an instance of your user control, and uses the method linked to above to hide all its content.

Comment: As far as I can see this explains how to customize the designer of a component, but I can't see how to entirely hide a user control in the designer view.

Comment: thanks for your help! I saw this post earlier. I tried the solution exactly as posted there but the popups still appear.

Comment: even throwing an exception in the render function (unconditionally and always) does not prevent the user control from beeing rendered!

Comment: I think VS just strips out the code blocks and puts the text from the ascx file into the designer (rendering any non-user controls), no render at all. That means you are stuck if you use a UserControl

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a usercontrol you can take advantage of the fact the designer ignores your code. I got the following to work:

create two styles in your user control:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hide
    {
        display:none;
    }
     .show
    {
        display:;
    }
</style>
```

create two asp panels in your usercontrol:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDesigner" runat="server" CssClass="show">
Put content you want to show in designer here
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDisplay" runat="server" CssClass="hide">
Put all your actual content here
</asp:Panel>
```

add this to your code:

```
 protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        pnlDisplay.CssClass = "show";
        pnlDesigner.CssClass = "hide";

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

For me this creates the desired effect of having a small block of text render in the designer for my user control

Comment: Probably should note that this hides things in the usercontrol designer as well, still works for me as I am editing the host pages a lot more than the usercontrols